# Ubuntu 16.04 64bits randomly freezes with caps lock blinking

Tags: 16.04, crash

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 64bits but after a couple of days of use I started noticing my pc randomly freezes with caps lock blinking. I have found this is probably due a kernel panic, but not sure how to solve it.

My machine is a Toshiba L50-B-1JU.

This is what I could recover from `kern.log`:

```
Jan  8 11:46:24 PJSS NetworkManager[949]: <info>  [1483875984.7192] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
Jan  8 12:00:05 PJSS kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
```

I have performed a memtest, here are the results
[Memtest Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSGQz.jpg)

Comment: Please add more information. Try to go to TTY1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>) and check for output. Or check `/var/log/kern.log`. Ahh kbd does not work...

Comment: What should I be looking in kern.log?

Comment: for any error/panic messages. Just edit your question and add the related lines.

Comment: Could you please [perform a memory test](/q/591488/175814) to see if your RAM is faulty? Thanks.

Comment: I could, but interestingly I don't have that option on the boot menu.
I can boot with different kernel versions, or go to bios, but no memtest